# how to show div if input is checked, PURE CSS

Tags: html, css, radio-button, checked

i am making a quiz using amp framework, and everything is almost done, i am purely using html and css to make this quiz without using any javascript.

for input I use radio button, and css myself I use Checked to display wrong! and correct! messages.

this is the CSS:

```
.quiz {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    display: grid;
}
.quiz > input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
.quiz__label {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.quiz__answer,
.quiz__explanation {
    max-height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: max-height 0.35s, opacity 0.1s;
}
.quiz__answer.correct {
    color: #2ecc71;
}
.quiz__answer.incorrect {
    color: #e60023;
}
```

this is CSS for displaying Explanation Text and wrong correct messages:

```
.quiz > input:checked + label > .quiz__answer {
    opacity: 1;
}
.quiz > input:checked ~ .quiz__explanation {
    max-height: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: var(--komen-color);
}
.quiz__explanation {
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

and this is the HTML:

```
<form method="post" action-xhr="#" target="_top">
    <h4>Select hashtags below that indicate the main purpose of the above information!</h4>
    <div class="quiz">
        <input class="quiz__radio" id="q1-answer1" name="tabs" type="radio" /><label class="quiz__label" for="q1-answer1">#document<span class="quiz__answer incorrect">Wrong!</span></label>
        <input class="quiz__radio" id="q1-answer2" name="tabs" type="radio" /><label class="quiz__label" for="q1-answer2">#inform<span class="quiz__answer correct">Correct!</span></label>
        <input class="quiz__radio" id="q1-answer3" name="tabs" type="radio" /><label class="quiz__label" for="q1-answer3">#sell<span class="quiz__answer incorrect">Wrong!</span></label>
        <input class="quiz__radio" id="q1-answer4" name="tabs" type="radio" /><label class="quiz__label" for="q1-answer4">#persuade<span class="quiz__answer incorrect">Wrong!</span></label>
        <input class="quiz__radio" id="q1-answer5" name="tabs" type="radio" /><label class="quiz__label" for="q1-answer5">#provoke<span class="quiz__answer incorrect">Wrong!</span></label>
        <input class="quiz__radio" id="q1-answer6" name="tabs" type="radio" /><label class="quiz__label" for="q1-answer6">#entertain<span class="quiz__answer incorrect">Wrong!</span></label>
        <div class="quiz__explanation"> // Message An explanation of the questions
            This text is an example explanation 
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

how to showing explanatory text if only correct answers are selected. if the answer is wrong, the explanation will not appear

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vhlan/pzx12hqf/5/)

Comment: Add `#q1-answer2:not(:checked) ~ .quiz__explanation {display: none;}` to the CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `correct`/`incorrect` classes to the radio buttons. So then you can use a selector to check both things at once (if it is checked and is wrong) using something like `input.incorrect:checked`.

HTML:

```html
<form method="post" action-xhr="#" target="_top">
    <h4>Select hashtags below that indicate the main purpose of the above information!</h4>
    <div class="quiz">
        <input class="quiz__radio incorrect" id="q1-answer1" name="tabs" type="radio" /><label class="quiz__label" for="q1-answer1">#document<span class="quiz__answer incorrect">Wrong!</span></label>
        <input class="quiz__radio" id="q1-answer2" name="tabs" type="radio" /><label class="quiz__label" for="q1-answer2">#inform<span class="quiz__answer correct">Correct!</span></label>
        <input class="quiz__radio incorrect" id="q1-answer3" name="tabs" type="radio" /><label class="quiz__label" for="q1-answer3">#sell<span class="quiz__answer incorrect">Wrong!</span></label>
        <input class="quiz__radio incorrect" id="q1-answer4" name="tabs" type="radio" /><label class="quiz__label" for="q1-answer4">#persuade<span class="quiz__answer incorrect">Wrong!</span></label>
        <input class="quiz__radio incorrect" id="q1-answer5" name="tabs" type="radio" /><label class="quiz__label" for="q1-answer5">#provoke<span class="quiz__answer incorrect">Wrong!</span></label>
        <input class="quiz__radio incorrect" id="q1-answer6" name="tabs" type="radio" /><label class="quiz__label" for="q1-answer6">#entertain<span class="quiz__answer incorrect">Wrong!</span></label>
        <div class="quiz__explanation">
            This text is an example
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS (add to yours)

```css
.quiz__explanation {
  opacity: 0;
}

input.incorrect:checked ~ .quiz__explanation {
    max-height: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: var(--komen-color);
}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eyz4o8k6/8/)